# Fuseki server down on Ubuntu: permission denied

Tags: jena, fuseki

I have been having an issue to access the Fuseki server. It seems to have been down for a while and I am getting a 404 Not Found Error when trying to access it via URL.

Through SSH I am trying to restart the fuseki server or at least check its status.

This is what I am doing:

```
/etc/default/fuseki start
```

But I am getting a

```
-bash: /etc/default/fuseki: Permission denied
```

Any idea why this is happening pls?

Comment: If you get a 404, then there a server of some kind at the URL. It is a response from a server saying here is no resource.

Comment: "Permission denied" is a local operating system error because the script is not executed by the user. Possibly, you need to sudo.